# Send values to another page without showing parameter at the end of url

Tags: php, url, post, get

We can get values from url like this.

```
abcd.com?id=123
```

We can get this id in php using

```
$id = $_get['id'];
```

But I see many urls like

```
abcd.com/123
```

How to do it and receive it in php page.

Comment: we call this "seo".

Comment: @Manikiran he needs the data in the url but in different format which is generally called seo friendly url's

Comment: Use .htaccess file with Rewrite Url Rules

Comment: You can use [AltoRouter](http://altorouter.com/)

Comment: @nandal assumption about OP's server environment.

Comment: Do you use a framework or plain PHP? Do you set the url's somewhere?

Comment: Can't we use the id as hidden field of the form? and post the data

Answer (score 1):

create a .htaccess file in webroot directory with

For numeric ID:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

For alphanumeric ID:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then, you can access domain.com/id as get parameter in index.php file

Answer (score 0):

for that you have multiple choices :

- Use a form and get params by POST,
- Or you can use the PHP_REQUEST_URI by parsing it and get the member you want, for example if your URL is like http://mywebsite.com/users/125, in that php global variable, you will find an entry as an array that will contain members of your URL ( [0] -> ... [1] -> ... ).
- Or, if you can use a Framework for examle Symfony, you will configure your routes and that's it.

Good Luck